# Создание телеграм-бота, играющего с пользователем в игру "Отгадай число"

Tags: python, telegram-bot

При создании телеграм-бота, играющего с пользователем в игру "Отгадай число", бот не реагирует на код после введения юзером первого числа, то есть он просит "Введите число" и после этого ничего не выдает. Подскажите, пожалуйста в чем ошибка кода?

````
import telebot
from telebot import types
from telebot import random

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def main(message):  

    markup_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item_guess = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='"Отгадай число"', callback_data='guess')
    markup_inline.row(item_guess) 

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data ==  'guess')
def callback_inline_second(call):

    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Я загадал число от 1 до 20. У Вас есть 5 попыток проверить свою интуицию и отгадать его.')
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Введите число')

@bot.message_handler(content_types='text')
def get_text_2(message):
    user_number = message.text
    number = random.randint(0, 20)
    attempt = 5
    while attempt>5:
    if user_number != number:
        attempt-=1
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Я загадал другое число. Осталось {attempt} попытки/а')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Вы отгадали!')

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'У Вас закончились попытки. Повезет в следующий раз!')```
````

Comment: заголовок совершенно не соответствует сути вопроса. вы в заголовке напишите, пожалуйста, кратко, что именно вы пытаетесь спросить.

Comment: У вас блок с `if`-ами не соответствует циклу `while`. Про отступы в питоне почитайте.

Comment: И еще, интересно, вы пишете "Я загадал другое число." и оставляете прежнее. Шулерский у вас бот!

Comment: А разве в telebot есть random? Может вы перепутали `from telebot import random` с `import random`